# What are the main differences between singleplayer and multiplayer mode?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What are the main differences between singleplayer and multiplayer mode, since a singleplayer world could be turned into multiplayer world. I'm not talking about how a player could behave in the game, I'm talking about the main logic differences underneath.

Also for a server hosting a game world, it could set maximum player number to only one. Then if a player starts this server on his own computer and then he joins the server, VS, say he simply plays a single player game. What are the differences between these two methods? Such as how the game treats the save files, how the game distinguishes these two methods, etc.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: It's the same. The only difference is the location of the map, which is usually on a dedicated server for multiplayer. The real difference is when it comes to plugins, such a spigot, etc., but in vanilla nope, no difference.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference.

The single player version is simply Minecraft creating a server that does not accept external connections.  It does the server creation part without asking for any input.

If you look at the background console for Minecraft during a single player game, it is doing exactly the same thing as a multiplayer server would.

Answer (score -2):

There is no difference except one.

**LAG**

minecraft will often lag giving you message of skipping x ticks and your system clock is behind few seconds. This happens because minecraft opens connection for other players to connect in. (I think it is called port forwarding. I am not sure what that term is).

I think that the lag occurs because (If 2 or more) players are playing then their respective chunks will be loaded and saved on the same hard drive at the same time on same disk.(that is due to harddrive speed limits).

If you do Open to Lan in single player and then allow others to join then you will experience similar issues. some of them are:

- you will suddenly go back to position you were few seconds before.
- you are trying to place a block. the block is placed at client side. but not on server side. This is dangerous if you are sneaking and placing blocks for building a bridge
- Troubles while fighting mobs. (I don't need to explain this. everyone knows. shhhhh........  BOOM)

Comment: port forwarding has *nothing* to do with lag.

Comment: Well. This answer was written after experimenting. I downloaded server and ran a world. Joined that server l. And it lagged. However playing directly single player gives me 100+ fps

Comment: fps is not lag. lag is network delay. It's not possible to lag when the server and client are on the same machine.

Comment: Have you tried it on pc yourself?